# Poner widget un poco más grande

Tags: javascript, css

Hay una página que me permite poner un widget de el precio del dólar, pero lo pone de un tamaño muy pequeño, hay forma de ponerlo al tamaño deseado?

Intenté con font-size, pero no me funciona, alguien sabe alguna manera?

```css
#indicadores{
    position: absolute;
    top: 730px;
    left: 380px;
    font-size: 180px;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me temo que sin ver el **HTML** que compone el elemento poco podemos hacer nosotros desde aquí. Si lo subes estoy seguro de que más de uno podrá echarte una mano.

Comment: Así es como lo puedo poner @PHPMyguel

Comment: Lo que interesaba es que inspeccionaras el elemento que te genera el script, con las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador y nos pegases el HTML, ya que así podremos ver lo que se debe modificar para hacer que salga más grande.

Comment: Así me sale en la consola @PHPMyguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por motivos de seguridad, es complicado hacer modificaciones en un iframe, aunque puede que se pueda, depende del componente y de dónde sale.

Si tienes la posibilidad de obtener el precio de otro sitio, te sugiero este otro ya que lo permite sin problemas, además, es el oficial:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .dolar-hoy-widget {
            display: none;
        }
        .tu_precio {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://www.dolarhoy.app/widget.js?t=1&c=1"></script>
    <div class="tu_precio"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".dolar-hoy-widget strong").clone().appendTo(".tu_precio");
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lo que hago es ejecutar el script oficial de dolarhoy y lo escondo para luego clonarlo en un div tuyo y darle formato. Supongo que puedes darle formato directamente en el div que crea el script, pero me era más cómodo así para no lidiar con el texto y los dos puntos.

Otra forma de hacerlo, según tus comentarios en el chat, sería usar la librería simple html dom que puedes bajar en http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Y podrías usar este código para sacar los valores:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html("https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators");

    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='BANREP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='ICAP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='OILVAL']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='COFFEE']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='DTF']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='UVR']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='EURCOP']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $html->find(".item-row[data-item='TIB']", 0)->find(".item-value > span", 0)->plaintext;
```

Esta forma en general, permite sacar los valores de cualquier web, aunque deberías consultar temas legales para saber si se puede o no. Yo más bien pienso que no, al menos en algunos paises.

Comment: Amigo, mira en esta misma página me muestra esto pero de esta manera. mira el código arriba, este si me lo deja poner grande, pero necesito que no se vea el titulo, como puedo hacer?

Comment: Para esconder un título, solo tienes que referenciarlo con css, con su id o su clase y añadirle display: none; creo que sería así: .texto_ind_todos { display: none; }

Comment: Por cierto, no queda claro como lo has conseguido y me gustaría saberlo, ¿tal vez has usado otro widget distinto de otra página? si es el caso y puedes hacerlo, hay miles de sitios en dónde te dejarán personalizarlo.

Comment: Pues la verdad he buscado bastantes sitios y no he visto ninguno asi parecido a este, de pronto no sabes de algún sitio? @track3r

Comment: Si, hay varias formas, yo lo haría usando algún plugin ya hecho como https://github.com/aacimov/jquery-currency-exchange-list como esto hace una petición al precio del dolar, puedes luego darle el formato que quieras y calcular lo que quieras.

Comment: He cambiado el código de mi respuesta con un ejemplo funcional sacado del precio de dolarohy.app

Comment: Ya con esa referencia puedo sacar los otros de esa página muchas gracias.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90634/discussion-between-lucas-suarez-and-track3r).

Comment: He añadido un método alternativo tal como sugieres en el chat.

Answer (score 2):

Tiene un cross domain iframe que de acuerdo a [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) no puedes modificar. No puedes modificar un `iframe` que viene desde un dominio diferente al tuyo. No lo puedes manipular desde javascript ni siquiera manipular su css.